# my class isn't working in this simple character movement script

Tags: python, class, pygame

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

bifl = 'screeing.jpg'
milf = 'char_fowed_walk1.png'

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 360),0, 32)
background = pygame.image.load(bifl).convert()
mouse_c = pygame.image.load(milf).convert_alpha()

x, y = 0, 0
movex, movey = 0, 0


class move:
    def moveUp():
        movey =- 0.3
    def moveDown():
        movey =+ 0.3
    def moveLeft():
        movex =- 0.3
    def moveRight():
        movex =+ 0.3

    def stopUp():
        movey = 0
    def stopDown():
        movey = 0
    def stopLeft():
        movex = 0
    def stopRight():
        movex = 0




while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                move.moveLeft()
            elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
                move.moveRight()
            elif event.key == K_UP:
                move.moveUp()
            elif event.key == K_DOWN:
                move.moveDown()

        if event.type == KEYUP:
             if event.key == K_LEFT:
                 move.stopLeft()
             elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
                 move.stopRight()
             elif event.key == K_UP:
                 move.stopUp()
             elif event.key == K_DOWN:
                 move.stopDown()

    x += movex
    y += movey

    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(mouse_c, (x, y))

    pygame.display.update()
```

when i run this everything works only that the player doesn't move, i testes this without classes and functions and it work so it's definitely something to do with the classes i added.
pygame is installed correctly i am using python 2.7 and i have used pygame in other scripts and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Since `movex` and `movey` are inside a function, they are locals, their values will never change outside the function (it will always be `0` from the `movex, movey = 0, 0` line). Read about variable scopes in Python.

You have to either put a `global movex` and `global movey` inside the `move` class or return the value of `movex` and `movey` on the functions, and use that returned value on the event capturing loop, like:

```
if event.key == K_LEFT:
    y += move.stopLeft()
```

I'd reorganize the entire thing and have a separate file for the move functions instead of a class, though.

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a totally different approach and store your x/y coordinations in a object that knows how to alter them:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

class Position(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0

    def moveUp(self):
        self.y =- 0.3

    def moveDown(self):
        self.y =+ 0.3

    def moveLeft(self):
        self.x =- 0.3

    def moveRight(self):
        self.x =+ 0.3

pos = Position()

movemap = {
    (KEYDOWN, K_LEFT): pos.moveLeft,
    (KEYDOWN, K_RIGHT): pos.moveRight,
    (KEYDOWN, K_UP): pos.moveUp,
    (KEYDOWN, K_DOWN): pos.moveDown,
}

bifl = 'screeing.jpg'
milf = 'char_fowed_walk1.png'

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 360),0, 32)
background = pygame.image.load(bifl).convert()
mouse_c = pygame.image.load(milf).convert_alpha()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        try:
            action = movemap[(event.type, event.key)]
        except KeyError:
            continue

        action()

    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(mouse_c, (pos.x, pos.y))

    pygame.display.update()
```

First, the Pythony stuff: in Python 2.7, classes should explicit inherit from `object`. That's the `class Position(object)` part. Also, the first argument to an instance method is an instance object. That's all the `self` stuff. Finally, you don't *have* to put regular functions in classes. It's perfectly OK to have a `dosomething(): return 5` function at the top level of a module.

Now, on to the rest:

A `Position` object knows how to mutate its own state. By making a dict that maps combinations of key events to methods, you don't have to have those long `if/elif/elif` blocks. You can also ignore every keyup event; just don't do anything unless the user is pressing a key.

Answer (score 0):

Zooming in a bit:

```
movex =- 0.3
```

You want

```
movex -= 0.3
```

your version is actually understood by python to be:

```
movex = (- 0.3)
```

Which is to say, negate `0.3` and assign the result to a *local* variable named `movex`,  Likewise:  `movex =+ 0.3`  is "make sure 0.3 is a number and assign it to movex".

In place operators put the operator *before* the equal sign.  Just fixing that will give you a somewhat helpful traceback, telling you that you can't assign a variable that hasn't been declared yet, since it still looks to the python interpreter like you want `movex` and `movey` to be locals.  Fixing that would be:

```
def moveLeft(self):
    global movex
    movex -= 0.3
```